# What does the red circle at the review queue pictogram mean?

Tags: support, review, user-interface

I've recently gained acesses to some review queues, but most of the times there's something to be reviewed (gray dot beside the queue), there's no notification saying so, other times I see a red dot but there's nothing there, as below:

[image]

What's the meaning of it?

Comment: I don't know if this is still true, but it used to be that the red or grey dot would appear if there were tasks to do, regardless of whether or not **you**, a user with a specific level of privilege, were able to do those tasks.

Comment: It is not a good indicator. Best to check the queue occasionally anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that reflects a kind of "urgency" about attending to the queue. If my recollection is right (it may be a bit off), blank means the queues are empty (or perhaps nearly so), a grey dot means there's a number of items in at least one queue (i.e. a queue needs attention) and red indicates there's at least one "long" queue.

Edit:

There's a pretty complete discussion on the network meta here:

[How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly)